# Insert object if key doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm using recharts to add a new line to a chart where the key value of the object equals to a key value from another object. It works fine when it finds the key but the script doesn't insert a new object if the key value is not found.

I have this array of objects in the state

```
{
  chartData: [
    { name: "100", line1: "332" },
    { name: "200", line1: "1235" },
    { name: "300", line1: "43534" },
    { name: "500", line1: "645324" },
    { name: "1000", line1: "345345" },
    { name: "2000", line1: "234234" },
    { name: "5000", line1: "654654" },
    { name: "10000", line1: "123" },
  ]
}
```

And this function that is adding a line where the values are the same

```
function addLine() {
  let newData = [
    { name: '100', line2: '6666' },
    { name: '230', line2: '2342342' },
    { name: '420', line2: '34234' },
    { name: '120', line2: '123656' },
    { name: '630', line2: '234245' },
  ];

  newData.map((io) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      chartData: prevState.chartData.map((el) =>
        el.name === io.name ? { ...el, line2: io.line2 } : { ...io, newData }
      ),
    }));
  });
}
```

How do I insert the values from `newData` that are not found in `chartData`?

An example could be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-toggle-legend-forked-i1qbd?file=/SampleChart.jsx:847-1310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newData.map((io) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    chartData: prevState.chartData.map((el) =>
      el.name === io.name ? { ...el, line2: io.line2 } : { ...io, newData }
    ),
  }));
});
```

Replace this with:

```
let chartData = this.state.chartData;
newData.map((io) => {
  const matchIdx = chartData.findIndex(el => el.name === io.name);
  if (matchIdx !== -1) {
    chartData[matchIdx] = {
      ...chartData[matchIdx],
      line2: io.line2
    };
  } else {
    chartData.push(io);
  }
});

this.setState({ chartData: chartData });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and inform me if it serves the result that you need

```
addLine() {
   const newData = [
      { name: "100", line2: "6666" },
      { name: "200", line2: "2342342" }
    ];
    const { chartData } = this.state;
    const modifiedData = chartData;
    // First add line2 values to the modifiedData array
    chartData.map((data, index) => 
      newData.map(({ name, line2 }) => {
        // Update the specific index with line2
        if (data.name === name)
          modifiedData[index] = { ...data, line2 };
        // push values that do not exist on modifiedData
        if (!modifiedData.some(modData => modData.name === name))
          modifiedData.splice(index, 0, { name, line2 }); // This is very important, if you want the new line to be connected if its data is not equal to chartData
        return data;
      })
    );
    this.setState({ chartData: modifiedData });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. The problem with this solution is that `line2` for example is not being added to the corresponding value of name, not sure if it makes sense but please have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-toggle-legend-forked-i1qbd?file=/SampleChart.jsx and click Add Line, as you can see a new line will be added and for that object with the same value, line2 will be added.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I got what you meant there, it got some time from me to figure it out, so hopefully your problem is fixed now

Comment: Recheck the code, I made an update to it, because I discovered some errors about it